# How to reactivate the network manager when the PC does not have access to the internet?

Tags: nvidia, network-manager, internet

The day before yesterday I installed the proprietary NVIDIA 535 driver and yesterday when I turned on the laptop, the place to log in did not appear. I managed to use GRUB to access the terminal and uninstall the driver using the purge command. I was then able to log in, but I was left without internet, the wifi icon disappeared, the cable internet didn't work, it seems that the network manager disappeared. Only the VPN icon remained.
I tried to restart Network Manager, but it didn't work.

With the command `nm-connection-editor` it generates the message that it cannot save the connection due to the error of

```
invalid configuration of wifi:802-11wirless.ssid: property is missing.
```

With the `nmcli` general status command, the information is that there is no connectivity or network, but that wifi is enabled.
So, as the PC does not access the internet, I cannot download/update packages.
My system is Ubuntu 22.04 lts
Can someone help me?